# How do I auto-insert a leading zero in Time notation

Tags: javascript, regex

The following code checks if the user inserted a correct time notation in a textbox.
If the notation is not correct an alert box will be shown.

It also shows an alert if a leading zero is forgotten (i.e. 7:45 iso 07:45)

```
function validateThis(e){
    //INPUT VALIDATION
        var regexp = /([01][0-9]|[02][0-3]):[0-5][0-9]/; //CORRECT TIME FORMAT
        var correct = (e.value.search(regexp) >= 0) ? true : alert('Enter time as hh:mm (13:25)');
    }
```

My question is how can I auto-insert a leading zero if forgotten rather than notifying the user

Comment: `('0' + value_to_lead_with_zero_or_not).substr(-2)`. This provides, that you split the time to hours and minutes and handle them separately. Notice, that the value of `correct` will be `undefined` when the condition is not passed. Also, the condition is never passed, `e` has no `value` property (in case `e` here is the event object). The ternary operator is not a shortcut to `if..else`, use `if..else` for the task here.

Comment: Why not just parse the input rather than relying on a regular expression? Split on the colon, test the values and (re)format accordingly.

Comment: BTW, your test will return true for many values that are likely not valid, such as 'qwe123412:23asd' since the pattern is found somewhere in the string. A better method is *test*, which returns a boolean, and you should limit the expression with `^` and `$`.

Answer (score 2):

You can compare the number (if string, convert it to number) with 10, if it's less than 10, add a zero, else, keep it as-is:

*note:* You can just split the string at colons and check for validity, no need for a regex.

```js
function leadZero(n) {
  return n < 10 ? "0" + n : n; 
}

function validateThis(e) {
  var hhmm = e.value.split(':'); // split into hh, mm
  // if there are two values (hh, mm) and
  // 0<=hh<=23 and 0<=mm<=59 => correct time
  
  var correct = false;
  
  if (hhmm.length === 2) {
    var [hh, mm] = hhmm;
    
    [hh, mm] = [+hh, +mm]; // +n in case of string, +n converts it to a number
    
    if ((hh>=0 && 23>=hh) && (mm>=0 && 59>=mm)) { // valid time
      correct = true;
    }
  }
  
  if (correct) {
    // add leading zeros
    //               fix hour                 fix minute
    var newTime = leadZero(hh) + ':' + leadZero(mm);
    console.log(newTime);
  } else {
    alert('Enter a valid time only');
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" onchange="validateThis(this)">
```

Comment: I didn't but how does this answers the question?

Comment: @Kaiido I updated my answer, but even before the update, my answer was enough, since it provided the tool that the OP needs to do whatever he wanted to do.

Comment: @Kaiido I provided the function that takes care of padding the zeros, I just left the trouble of implementing it to the OP, but I guess he's a beginner, so it wasn't enough.

Comment: Yes, with his implementation of taking the input as a whole, that was pretty useless. Now your answer is fine.

Comment: Shouldn't 5: result in  05:00 instead of 05:0 ?
And 1:00 should be formatted as 01:00 instead of 01:000

Answer (score 1):

You may try the following approach:

```js
function verify()
{

var str=$("#time").val();
var patt = new RegExp("^(0?[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]$");

if(patt.test(str))
  {
    if(str.length==4)
      $("#time").val("0"+str);
    console.log("true");
  }
else
  console.log("false");



}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="time" id="time" value="" />
<input type="button" name="sbmt" id="sbmt" value="Submit" onclick="verify();">
```

Answer (score 0):

With all your help I produced the following:

```js
function validate(e) {
  var regexp = /([0-9]|0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]/;

  if ((e.value.search(regexp) >= 0)) {
    e.value.length == 4 ? document.getElementById(e.id).value = '0' + e.value : 0;
  } else {
    alert('Time is not entered correctly, enter like hh:mm');
  }
}
```

```html
<div>
  <label for="name">Time</label>
  <input id="lbl3" class='input' type="text" onchange="validate(this);">
</div>
```

Comment: It's still alerting when I enter `13:2`. My answer ignores this and saves the time as `13:02`.

Comment: Your right Mr Geek, I didn't think about that :) .My biggest concern where the hours. Thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score -1):

First, you should change your regexp so it'll be able to validate both cases with and without leading zeros.
If the input is valid you can modify the input with one of the offered solutions or any other.